# How does $(objectName) work in Scala Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-ml

Hi I am trying to learn org.apache.spark.ml design. I noticed in that param values are often retrieved by using $ symbol. 
For example, in [NGram.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.5/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/NGram.scala)

```
val n: IntParam = new IntParam(this, "n", "number elements per n-gram (>=1)", 
  ParamValidators.gtEq(1))

/** @group setParam */
def setN(value: Int): this.type = set(n, value)

/** @group getParam */
def getN: Int = $(n)
```

Is $ a Scala operator with general features?

I can see in eclipse (when I hoverover `$(n)`) that it is defined as

`final protected def $[T](param: Param[T]): T`

but I could not find the class where it was defined the above way.

Can you please tell me where this is defined ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dollar sign is a perfectly legal method name in Scala. You can see the definition of this method [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/098be27ad53c485ee2fc7f5871c47f899020e87b/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/param/params.scala#L474).

In this case, it is simply an alias for `getOrDefault`.

Comment: Wow! Don't know how I missed it! I looked at this source code :-(. Thank you!